# Laravel on VestaCP throws error 500. What file should I update to solve this problem?

Tags: laravel

When i try visiting my site I get this error, when I look domain.com.error.log:

```
PHP Fatal error: require(): Failed opening required '/home/<user/web/<domain>/public_html/../vendor/autoload.php
```

Files from my laravel project are placed into domain folder, files from public folder are inserted into /public_html folder. I've tried composer update, generate key, and all the other composer commands that people adviced here before.

I've set all my directories permissions to 777, so this error cannot be because of lacking permissions.

If you need any additional information, please ask, trying to solve this problem for 4 days already.

Edit: Solved this problem, it appeared because php didn't have access to files that are not inside public_html. So, this can be solved by either putting all your project into public_html folder, or updating your server rules to allow php access the folder with the project.

Comment: don't give 777 permission for folder it `755` and for file it `644`

Answer (score 1):

**You need to install composer from** [www.getcomposer.org](http://www.getcomposer.org)

```
composer dump-autoload
composer install --no-dev --no-interaction --prefer-dist --optimize-autoloader
php artisan cache:clear
php artisan route:cache
php artisan view:clear
php artisan migrate --force
```

Comment: its Working Dude?

Comment: In progress, a little problem with migration, but site still throws 500

Comment: Solved the problem with migration, but 500 error is still there(